# h2 connection test failed when run ./gradlew build

Tags: java, gradle, jdbc, h2

I got JdbcSQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException when run ./gradlew build
If i click the run button from intellij, my tests passed.

```
UserDaoJdbcImpTest > initializationError FAILED
    java.lang.RuntimeException at UserDaoJdbcImpTest.java:52
        Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException at UserDaoJdbcImpTest.java:32
```

```
private static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=POSTGRESQL";
    private static final String USER = "sa";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "";
    private UserDaoJdbc userDaoJdbc;
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "user_details";

    @BeforeAll
    public static void setUpDatabase() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        try(Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASSWORD);
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {

            // setup user_details table
            ;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if i change it to DB_URL to, ./graldew build works, i guess it might because jdbc:h2:mem:db is used for an in-memory database that exists only for the duration of your application's runtime

```
private static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:h2:~/test;MODE=POSTGRESQL";
```